# android ImageView vs canvas for game

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I´m new in android development. I want to create a game where the user needs to quickly drag and drop balls with the finger in the screen to specific locations in order to win.
I don´t know if i can do this with simple ImageViews or i need to use canvas or other thing to draw in the screen.
I have tried to drag and drop an ImageView on top of another ImageView but it does not seem to work very well and i'm hesitating if i need to do it drawing figures instead of using the ImageViews or to do something else.
Please advice. Any help is apreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageViews are Views designed to hold image drawables, which isn't really needed in your case - you can use a simple View with a color background or  implemended `onDraw` method, you can use an ImageView just as well.
Asfor the drag and drop, what you need is any View with implemented `onTouch` method so that the view changes its position on screen with ACTION_MOVE touch events.
If you're interested, i have implemented a simple frame layout with drag and drop functionality. My layout requires long-click to start drag, but it can be easily modified so it won't. Check it out at [my github page](https://github.com/maciekjanusz/draglayout). You can clone the project and run demo activity to see how it works, and start from there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i´ll take a look at your framework as example